# Makefile: apply text transforming function on define argument

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to improve my Makefile by using `define` as functions, but I have a little problem with Make functions in defines. Let me show you a demo

```
OBJ=obj/main.o \
    obj/prompt.o

define buildMessage
    src="$(patsubst $(OBJ_PREFIX)/%.o,%.c,$(1))"; \
    obj="$(patsubst $(OBJ_PREFIX)/%.o,%.o,$(1))"; \
    echo "$$src => $$obj"
endef

$(OBJ):
    $(call buildMessage, "$@")
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $(patsubst $(OBJ_PREFIX)/%.o, $(SRC_PREFIX)/%.c, $@) $(CFLAGS)
```

So, yeah, I want the define to print the build step with fancy style, but it seems that the `patsubst` isn't applied in the *define*. It will output

```
obj/main.o => obj/main.o
obj/prompt.o => obj/prompt.o
```

It is exactly like if the patsubst was handled but without changing nor matching anything. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time

Alex

Comment: Shouldn't `src=` have `SRC_PREFIX` instead of `OBJ_PREFIX`?

Comment: No matter, I don't have the var containing the SRCs. Moreover, this is not really the problem of the post: the problem is more about why patsubst isn't doint its job

Comment: Just a note:, this doesn't _simplify_ the makefile.  You'll end up finding that if you use extensive macros in makefiles, they'll be harder to read, and you'll be the only person who can support it -- speaking from experience here.   There are times when they are useful, but I have learned to avoid them, unless they provide a real benefit.   In your case, you can better accomplish your goal with a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).

Comment: Are you talking about the `define buildMessage` ? Because if it's the case, I can't see how to use static rules and what is the benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that, although you didn't show it, the value of `OBJ_PREFIX` is `obj`.

Make doesn't care anything about quotes.  When you write:

```
$(call buildMessage, "$@")
```

the value of `$1` will be, literally, `"obj/main.o"` including the quotes.  That string doesn't match the pattern `obj/%.o` and so the pattern doesn't apply, leaving the original string untouched.

You should write this:

```
$(call buildMessage,$@)
```